# Will `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND())` in spark provide me a random row number for each row?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to get a random sample from a spark tempView, will the below provide me a random row number for each of the rows in the spark sql temp view?

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) as rn
  FROM my_temp_view
)
```

And then if I want a random sample of 1000 rows I would just

```
SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY rn LIMIT 1000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks correct, but if all you want is e.g. a random sampling of 1000 records, I don't even see the point of using `ROW_NUMBER`.  Instead, just use a limit query directly:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_temp_view
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1000;
```